# Deutsch Algorithm on a Quantum Turing Machine

Tags: quantum-algorithms, simulation, quantum-turing-machine, deutsch-jozsa-algorithm

I understood how a Quantum Turing Machine works from [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwjF95m-mrveAhUZdCsKHQKBCHUQFjAAegQIBRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpeople.eecs.berkeley.edu%2F~vazirani%2Ff97qcom%2Flec19.ps&usg=AOvVaw3q_ZVoVtCMMG8hLif0NA4U) lecture.

It would be great if someone could give an example of how this machine could be used to solve a real problem though, for example, simulate the Deutsch algorithm on a Quantum Turing machine.

Comment: Can you provide a better link? Currently it goes to a postscript file. For example, a link to the course website would be more helpful.

Comment: very shortly, the quantum Turing machine is simply a mathematical model for the functioning of a quantum computer, used to formalise arguments about algorithmic efficiency and such. It is not useful to solve "real problems", in the same sense that the classical turing machine isn't. It is useful in providing a way to reason about algorithms running on a quantum computer in a rigorous way.